# javascript not working in android 3.0

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-3.0-honeycomb

i found a sample app in the following link

http://code.google.com/p/chaek/

The app is an epub reader, monocle library, in which the book is been loaded and it use to change by each page. The main part of the app is based on the java script code.

When i run the code in my android mobiles it is working fine, that the ebook gets loaded and i am able to change it page wise, when i try the app in my Samsung tablet of android 3.1 the book gets loaded but not able to change it pagewise its get changed chapter wise.

When i tried to print some log error, i get the following line only from my tablet

```
[METHOD] void openChapter(chapNo:1)
[CALLBACK_WV] void onPageStarted(view:android.webkit.WebView@40d32f58, url:file:///mnt/sdcard/gisbook/.9789026324710/OEBPS/html/, favicon:null)
[CALLBACK_WV] void onPageFinished(view:android.webkit.WebView@40d32f58, url:file:///mnt/sdcard/gisbook/.9789026324710/OEBPS/html/)
javascript:getTotalPageNum()
javascript:openPageByPercentage(0.0)
Uncaught ReferenceError: getTotalPageNum is not defined at null:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: openPageByPercentage is not defined at null:1
```

Whereas in from android mobiles the above lines are as follows

```
 [CALLBACK_WV] void onPageStarted(view:android.webkit.WebView@44f4a130, url:file:///sdcard/.9789026324710/OEBPS/html/, favicon:null)
 [CALLBACK_WV] void onPageFinished(view:android.webkit.WebView@44f4a130, url:file:///sdcard/.9789026324710/OEBPS/html/)
 javascript:getTotalPageNum()
 javascript:openPageByPercentage(0.0)
 [BRIDGE] void setTotalPageNum(page:1)
 [METHOD] void selectBookmark()
```

Why such a difference between android mobiles and tablets, is the webview a problem in android tablets ie3.0 and above version

i shared this problem with its author of the code he is also not able to get an idea on this.

When i was googling regarding this i came across lot  of programmers saying issue on java script working on webview. i tried out most of their answers but no use.

Can anyone explain me or figure out why such an error... pls

Comment: If I understood you right, you're having the same problem as me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711225/javascript-not-working-in-a-webview-activity/8712809#8712809 Until now I can say that the code works on Androi 2.3, but on the Tablet with 3.2 not. It seems that the DOM is building too slow. But just a guess.

Comment: i have already seen your answer and tried it, but no use. Anyhow thanks....

Answer (score 3):

I got exactly the same error and it appears only on Honeycomb and Ice Cream Sandwich. On Gingerbread it works fine.

The way I worked around it was to use "`<script src=...></script>`" instead of "`<script src=.../>`". I'd never think that this would make a difference, but it does. Seems to be a webkit bug.

Comment: You have to do this replacement in the HTML loaded by your WebView.

Comment: Better ask monocle's author where to find the HTML it uses.

Comment: Did you ask monocle's author? Did you check whether making this change fixes the problem? BTW, I filed a bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28840

Comment: i have chatted with the author and he said he will try to fix to fix it, that too a long time before.....

Answer (score 1):

scriptElement.setAttribute("src", "url('file:///android_asset/" + path + "')");

needs to be replaced with this one:

scriptElement.setAttribute("src", "file:///android_asset/" + path);