# Javascript not working in a WebView Activity

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have an Activity that has just a **WebView**, which contains HTML, CSS and Javascript Code.

It seems that there's a problem with the **access** of **Javascript** to the **screen size** of the view.
LogCat says:

```
(Tag: Web Console): Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getWidth' of undefined 
at file:///android_asset/Prospekte/grund/html5-player/js/epaper-mobile.js:20
```

When I look into the js-file, there is: `var f=this.body.getWidth();`

There curious thing is that **sometimes the code works**. The epaper is shown well. But most time there's this error.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.prospekt_layout);
    final Activity activity = this;

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.prospekt_webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
      }
    });

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });   

    mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Prospekte/modKachel/mobile.html");
```

The layout is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/prospekt_webview"
    android:layout_width="900px"
    android:layout_height="900px"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I changed the size of the webView cause I thought that this could be the solution..but it's no working with dp either.

Someone has in idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set this setting as well for your webView:

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

For Detail refer to answer in the following link:
 [ERROR/Web Console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getItem' of null at http://m.youtube.com/:844](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822256/error-web-console-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-getitem-of-null-at-h)

**Update:**
or adding this might help:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://fake.com", myString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried that already. My mistake that I deleted this in the code. So when I tested this, the first time it worked, the second time it didn't. Is it possible that there's a problem with time? Maybe the DOM can't be built fast enough? I tried an AsyncTask, but that didn't help, too.

Comment: Well can't say anything like issue with time or etc.

Comment: Thanks, a step forward: when I paste the first HTML-Code into "myString", the code worked. But now, I've got another HTML-Code which should work pretty the same like the one before. But there's a script written that's shown when Javascript is disabled it seems: "Please activate javascript". The HTML-code isn't written by me, just for information. Are there further Javascript-settings that I could enable?

Comment: No i haven't seen any other properties for javascript yet. You also have to set your java script enabled to true along with these properties. I hope you did not set that to false...And if this worked for you...mark it as accepted answer...:-)

Comment: No, I have set it to true ;-). It seems that the DOM just can't be build fast enough. Like if the external .js-files couldn't get loaded before the HTML-content is shown. That could be a reason, cause the HTML-page is linking 5 js.-Files. 1 out of 15 trys are successfull, the page is illustrated correctly. But the other times it seems that the code couldn't be loaded fast enough. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes! You are right..DOM is slower than other available parsers.

Comment: So I could use a separate parser to load the html? Do you know some?

Comment: So I would have to code the whole thing in JSON? Or is there a way to transform it?

Comment: Well it depends upon your requirements. you definitely can receive same data in JSON instead of DOM...but i haven't actually transformed it till now. So i don't know how to do it. But this is doable. If you can write DOM you can write JSON too...

Comment: Ok, thanks! So you guess that I would have to translate it by hand? Or isn't it excluded that there's a way to do it automatically? Cause the javascript-Code is too long to transcribe it. Or is it just the HTML-Code that I would have to transcribe?

Comment: Well i am not sure about that.

Comment: I had the chance to test it on another device with Android 2.3 and now it works. So it was just a problem of the particular tablet, on which Android 3.2 was installed. But I still have to make it work on the tablet. Does anyone have an idea what could be the reason for this?

Comment: DOM storage helped me.

Answer (score 4):

You should implicitly enable Javascript execution in your WebView, since this could cause XSS and other vulnerabilities.

```
web = new WebView(this);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Also, I prefer to set my WebViewClient via

```
WebViewClient webViewMainWebClient = new WebViewClient()
{
   // Override page so it's load on my view only
   @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url)
   {
       // Return true to override url loading (In this case do nothing).
       return false;
   }
}
web.setWebViewClient(this.webViewMainWebClient);
```

to let me restrict usage of only my sites.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem on android 3.2. A solution that works for me (pretty ugly) is to put a sleep and call another loadUrl, try with more time if 300ms is not sufficient:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/gabarit.html");
try {
    Thread.sleep(300);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/gabarit.html");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my Mo Da Browser project. I added these two lines:

```
    wvOptions.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wvOptions.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

wvOptions is just webview.getSettings() stored in a var.
The second line seems to have solved the problem.
The first line gives users control over the resulting web page's size.
You could add the "open in overview" option if you liked the result.
That didn't help me so I used the zoom option.

Comment: `+1` OMG these two lines made my day. My **HTML** and **CSS** were correctly rendering but **JS** was loading forever. I add these two lines: `wvOptions.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);` and `wvOptions.setUseWideViewPort(true);` and it is working now. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This may fix your problem. You probably mistakenly named the script tag to `<scripts>` instead of `<script>` in your HTML code because you were developing in android studio.